# Retrieving the column value behind a foreign key using mysql

Tags: mysql

Please I would be very glad if someone puts me through this hassle

I have two tables by name employee and borrowed

```
employee:
id  firstname   lastname    birthdate
1   John         Smith      1976-01-02
2   Laura        Jones      1969-09-05
3   Jane         Green      1967-07-15

borrowed
ref employeeid          book
1       1             Simply SQL
2       2             Ultimate HTML Reference
3       1             Ultimate CSS Reference
4       3             Art and Science of JavaScript
```

**My question is this: How do i retrieve the only the name of the person that borrowed the book "Art and Science of Javascript"**

This is my failed sql code.

```
SELECT book FROM borrowed 
JOIN employee ON employee.id=borrowed.employeeid 
WHERE borrowed.book='Art and Science of Javascript';
```

Thanks in advance as I anticipate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, all you need to do is to `SELECT employee.firstname` and `employee.lastname`

This should do it:

```
SELECT e.firstname, e.lastname 
FROM employee e
JOIN borrowed b ON e.id=b.employeeid 
WHERE b.book='Art and Science of Javascript';
```

If you want both first name and last name in single column then you can use MySQL's `CONCAT` function, e.g.:

```
SELECT CONCAT(employee.firstname, ' ', employee.lastname) AS name FROM..
```

**Update** You can also use sub-query to get the same result, e.g.:

```
SELECT CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) AS name
FROM employee WHERE id IN (
    SELECT employeeid 
    FROM borrowed 
    WHERE book = 'Art and Science of Javascript'
);
```

Comment: i did exactly ask you wrote but got an error that read:  Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'confirmed'

Comment: I have updated the query with table aliases, try now?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks good except the select part.

```
 SELECT  firstname,lastname  FROM borrowed 
 JOIN employee ON employee.id=borrowed.employeeid 
  WHERE borrowed.book='Art and Science of Javascript';
```

It would be better if you use alias for table names but your current code is correct except the select clause